# WebRTC stream to RTSP

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp

I believe the question is fairly straight forward in the title.  I have the WebRTC stream however my end program consume RTSP streams.  Is there a simple way to convert the stream from WebRTC to RTSP?

There is no latency requirement.

Comment: Use some media server middleware that will convert incoming webrtc to outcoming rtsp. live555 maybe will do it. Unreal Media Server + happytime rtsp server will do it. Wowza may do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably reduce some of the indirection, but I would use [rtp-forwarder](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/rtp-forwarder) to take WebRTC -> RTP.

You can then push these via `ffmpeg` into an RTSP server! The `README.md` shows how to playback the media directly. Instead just push using ffmpeg into your RTSP server. `ffmpeg -i rtp-forwarder.sdp -protocol_whitelist file,udp -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://$RTSP_SERVER:8888/live.sdp`

Comment: Thanks Sean! I think this was what I was looking for.